# Can I set a breakpoint in ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitializeProcess?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, windbg

When debugging a Windows process, it would sometimes be convenient to break as early as possible.

Inital Callstack looks like this: (you get this e.g. when you set a breakpoint in a `DllMain` function on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`)

```
    ...
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x14 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpRunInitializeRoutines@4()  + 0x205 bytes 
>   ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitializeProcess@20()  - 0x96d bytes    
    ntdll.dll!__LdrpInitialize@12()  + 0x6269 bytes 
    ntdll.dll!_KiUserApcDispatcher@20()  + 0x7 bytes
```

so setting a breakpoint in one of these ntdll routines should really break the process very early.

However, I can't figure out how to set a breakpoint there *prior to starting the process in the debugger*. Is it possible in Visual Studio (2005)? How? Can it be done in WinDbg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out how to do it in Visual Studio.

The problem here is, that setting a breakpoint in any assembly function will be remembered as a "Data Breakpoint". These breakpoints are disabled as soon as the process stops, so even if I set one in this function (I can do this because I have the function on the stack if I set a breakpoint in any DllMain function) this breakpoint will be disabled for a new process run.

*However* for ntdll.dll (and kernel32.dll) the load addresses are pretty much fixed and won't change (and least not until reboot).

So, before starting the process, I just have to re-enable the Data Breakpoint for the address that corresponds to this NtDll function and the debugger will then stop there.

Comment: They won't even change when you reboot. Why would they? They might change when you install a system update that modifies the DLL but those DLLs will load at their preferred base address every time.

Comment: @David: What about [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)?

Comment: And do you enable ASLR in your app?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: since Vista you don't really "enable" ASLR in an app, it's on by default.

Answer (score 6):

I would use something like [GFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549557%28VS.85%29.aspx) to launch the debugger when the process starts.

Here is a sample gflags settings for test.exe

[image]

And here is the debugger output. Notice the call-stack with  `ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess`

> CommandLine: "C:\temp\test.exe" 
>   Symbol search path is:
>   srv*;srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
>   Executable search path is:  ModLoad:
>   00000000`00d20000 00000000`00d28000
>   image00000000`00d20000 (1b40.464):
>   Break instruction exception - code
>   80000003 (first chance)
>   ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
>   00000000`77c7cb60 cc              int 
>   3 0:000> k Child-SP          RetAddr
>   Call Site 00000000`0012ed70
>   00000000`77c32ef5
>   ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30
>   00000000`0012edb0 00000000`77c11a17
>   ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x1b4f
>   00000000`0012f2a0 00000000`77bfc32e
>   ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x29220
>   00000000`0012f310 00000000`00000000
>   ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe

Or you could open the process within the debugger like Windbg which would break into `ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess` by default.

HTH